# Can I share registered servers across multiple copies of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-management-studio

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I use Registered Servers to save all my database connections that I use on a daily basis. I am looking to find a way I can save the settings of these Registered Servers, so I can use them on both my home and work machines. Ideally I would be able to save some sort of configuration file that both machines use on my OneDrive account, so any change on one machine is reflected on the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of user authentication on the registered server in order for each user to access the server from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

It might be worth noting that the support for accessing a server from multiple endpoints is still limited on some platforms and applications if the server does not support multiple instances. 
note - (Largely dependent on the software development)